# How to create html using user input and display it in a new tab?

Tags: python, flask

I would like to run a flask application where the user can provide some user input which is used to create a HTML page which should then be displayed in a new tab. The HTML is created using an external tool (here mimicked by the function `get_html` which actually takes the user input as argument), so I cannot just use a template which I render (I think).

I can already take the user input and create the HTML I would like to see displayed, however, I did not manage to also open a new tab for it. How can this be achieved?

Here is my code:

```
from __future__ import print_function, division

from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify
import json

# Initialize the Flask application
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/html_in_tab')
def get_html():

    # provided by an external tool 
    # takes the user input as argument (below mimicked by a simple string concatenation)

    return '<!DOCTYPE html><title>External html</title><div>Externally created</div>'


@app.route('/_process_data')
def data_collection_and_processing():

    # here we collect some data and then create the html that should be displayed in the new tab
    some_data = json.loads(request.args.get('some_data'))

    # just to see whether data is retrieved
    print(some_data)

    # oversimplified version of what actually happens; get_html comes from an external tool
    my_new_html = get_html() + '<br>' + some_data
    print(my_new_html)

    # this html should now be displyed in a new tab
    return my_new_html


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app.run(debug=True)
```

The `index.html` looks as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="header">
        <h3 class="text-muted">Get new tab!</h3>
      </div>
      <button type="button" id="process_input">Process!</button>

      <a href="/html_in_tab" class="button" target='_blank'>Go to results</a>

    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {

        // clicking the button works fine: data is processed correctly
        $('#process_input').bind('click', function() {
            $.getJSON('/_process_data', {
                some_data: JSON.stringify('some data')

            });
          // can this be changed to show the processed html?
          window.open("/html_in_tab", "_blank");
          return false;

        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

So, now the `window.open` part opens a new tab, but it should display `my_new_html`, the newly created HTML by `data_collection_and_processing`. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment you're just opening a new window at the endpoint `"/html_in_tab"` which will hit the Flask route for `get_html()` and show the standard HTML with no user input.

One method you could try is to open a new window and set the document body innerHTML with the updated content:

```
<script type="text/javascript">                                             
  $(document).ready(function() {                                            

    $('#process_input').bind('click', function() {                          

        $.get('/_process_data', {                                           

            some_data: JSON.stringify('some data'),                         

        }).success(function(data) {                                         

                var win = window.open("", "_blank");                        
                win.document.body.innerHTML = data;                         

        })                                                                  

        return false;                                                       

    });                                                                     
  });                                                                       
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the immediate reply! That seems to work (upvoted). Do you see an even more elegant solution for this or would this be the way to go?

Comment: Hard to say without knowing the real world constraints of your get_html function. If the HTML format is standard, you might wish to simply pass in the user input to the Flask route and pass that input to Flask's render_template function. If you need to call the external service to get the HTML then my answer posted above is probably a good enough solution.

Comment: Ok, thanks once more. Right now, I need this external tool to create the entire page which I then display. Will check whether I can access the source code and then might be able to extract the relevant parts for the html creation; then I could create a template and indeed use the `render_template` directly.

Answer (score 1):

Change your html as shown below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="header">
        <h3 class="text-muted">Get new tab!</h3>
      </div>
      <button type="button" id="process_input">Process!</button>

      <a href="/html_in_tab" class="button" target='_blank'>Go to results</a>

    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {

        // clicking the button works fine: data is processed correctly
        $('#process_input').bind('click', function() {
            $.getJSON('/_process_data', {
                some_data: JSON.stringify('some data')

            }); 
          // can this be changed to show the processed html?
          window.open("/process_data", "_blank");
          return false;

        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and Python script as shown below:

```
from __future__ import print_function, division

from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify
import json
# Initialize the Flask application
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/html_in_tab')
def get_html():

    # provided by an external tool
    return '<!DOCTYPE html><title>External html</title><div>Externally created</div>'


@app.route('/_process_data')
def data_collection_and_processing():
    # here we collect some data and then create the html that should be displayed in the new tab
    some_data = json.loads(request.args.get('some_data'))
    # just to see whether data is retrieved
    print(some_data)

    # oversimplified version of what actually happens; get_html comes from an external tool
    my_new_html = get_html() + '<br>' + some_data
    with open('templates/changed_html.html','w') as f: #write the html string to file
        f.writelines(my_new_html)
    # this html should now be displyed in a new tab
    return ''

@app.route('/process_data')
def process_data():
    return render_template('changed_html.html')

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Thanks! That works fine, too (upvoted), but seems slower than the other solution and then also requires to create temporary files which I would like to avoid...