# script in HTML string is not executed when passed via JSON

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, flask

This is a follow-up question of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49625787/1534017).

Goal is to use some user input that is converted to a HTML document that should be displayed in a new tab (that's answered in the link above).

Problem is, however, that - if the HTML document contains `<script>` tags - those are not executed when this HTML string is passed as JSON. Below I use a simple string:

```
'<!DOCTYPE html><title>External html</title><div>Externally created</div><script>alert("WORKING");</script>'
```

This is a minimal example to illustrate the problem (you will see this in your browser when you load the HTML from below):

[image]

When I click on the button, the new tab is opened but the script is not executed i.e. there is no alert shown. By clicking on the `alert` link, the html string is loaded directly and the alert is shown correctly.

My question is, how to postprocess the HTML string that is returned from `.getJSON` to execute the script correctly. Currently I do it like this (entire code can be found below):

```
$.get('/_process_data', {

                some_data: JSON.stringify('some data'),

            }).success(function(data) {

                    var win = window.open("", "_blank");
                    win.document.body.innerHTML = data;

            })
```

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="header">
        <h3 class="text-muted">Get new tab!</h3>
      </div>
      <button type="button" id="process_input">no alert</button>

      <a href="/html_in_tab" class="button" target='_blank'>alert</a>

    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#process_input').bind('click', function() {

            $.get('/_process_data', {

                some_data: JSON.stringify('some data'),

            }).success(function(data) {

                    var win = window.open("", "_blank");
                    win.document.body.innerHTML = data;

            })
            return false;
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and the flask file:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify
import json

# Initialize the Flask application
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/html_in_tab')
def get_html():

    # provided by an external tool
    # takes the user input as argument (below mimicked by a simple string concatenation)

    return '<!DOCTYPE html><title>External html</title><div>Externally created</div><script>alert("WORKING");</script>'


@app.route('/_process_data')
def data_collection_and_processing():

    # here we collect some data and then create the html that should be displayed in the new tab
    some_data = json.loads(request.args.get('some_data'))

    # just to see whether data is retrieved
    print(some_data)

    # oversimplified version of what actually happens; get_html comes from an external tool
    my_new_html = get_html() + '<br>' + some_data
    print(my_new_html)

    # this html should now be displyed in a new tab
    return my_new_html


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index_new_tab.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need something like this:

```
var win = window.open("", "_blank",);
win.document.write('<!DOCTYPE html><title>External html</title><div>Externally created</div><script>(function(){alert(1);})();</script>');
```

when you open the popup, this executes JavaScript. You could add data and do whatever you want inside `<script>(function(){alert(data);})();</script>`

Comment: Oha, `win.document.write(data);` indeed shows the alert (instead of `win.document.body.innerHTML = data;`)! That looks promising, thanks!

Comment: @Cleb if data is an string or something you want to show: win.document.write('<!DOCTYPE html><title>External html</title>+data+<div>Externally created</div><script>(function(){alert(1);})();</script>'); or similar

Comment: `data` is the entire HTML string including the `<script>` part.

Answer (score 1):

After the HTML has been added to the page, you could execute a function to run it. This would require wrapping your scripts with functions like this:

```
function onStart() {
    // Your code here
}
```

Then after the HTML is added to the page, run the function:

```
$.get('/_process_data', {

    some_data: JSON.stringify('some data'),

}).success(function(data) {

    var win = window.open("", "_blank");
    win.document.body.innerHTML = data;
    onStart();
})
```

Comment: What code would then actually go to `Your code here`? The `<script>` content?

Comment: Whatever you want for the script. In your case, it would be the `alert()`.

Comment: In my actual application, the content of the `scripts` is generated by an external tool, so I would not know how to create this function `onStart`. The detailed question [can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50293416/bokeh-plot-is-not-shown-when-used-getjson-and-flask). I will check whether I can use your approach and get back to you. There is no magic `execute all scripts you find` function by any chance?! ;)

Comment: And then I still don't understand why it actually works by clicking on the link; when I inspect the code, it looks identical but one time, the script is executed the other time it isn't.

Comment: If the tool outputs a string, you could do something like `"<script>function onStart() {" + (insert a string of JS here) + "}</script>`. But this assumes that your using JS. If your using another language with the tool, you would have to figure out how strings work in it.

Comment: The tool already outputs the entire string including the `<script>` part, I just don't know why it is not executed.

Comment: It's the way the JS is executed. The code your adding is added after the page has loaded. The reason that it could work sometimes could depend on how quickly it's getting the actual script and adding it to the page.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of...

```
var win = window.open("", "_blank"); 
win.document.body.innerHTML = data;
```

Use jquery to load the html and wait for loading to complete:

```
$.get('/_process_data', {

    some_data: JSON.stringify('some data'),

}).success(function(data) {

    var w = window.open("", "_blank");
    $(w.document.body).load(data, function () {
        //execute javascript here 
    });

})
```

Comment: So what goes into the `//execute javascript here` section? :) I should update the question I guess; `data` is the entire HTML string which I showed in my question, so all the javascript is already included, I just don't know who to execute it correctly.